# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode9

I've converted my iOS Project from swift 2.x to swift 3.x
There are now more then 50 errors in my code. One of the most common is this one "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'AnyObject'"

Here is a part of the code:

the line `let documentURL = JSON[eachOne]["media"]!![eachMedia]["media_url"]!` is producing the error

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you!

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
    //print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    myDefaultValues.userDefaults.setValue(JSON, forKey: "JSON")

    for eachOne in 0 ..< (JSON as AnyObject).count{
        // print("Cover: \(JSON[eachOne]["cover"])")

        //Download all Covers
        let documentURL = JSON[eachOne]["cover"]!
        let pathus = URL(string: documentURL as! String)

        if pathus != nil {
            HttpDownloader.loadFileSync(pathus!, completion:{(path:String, error:NSError!) in

            })
        }

        //Download all Media Files
        if JSON[eachOne]["media"] != nil{
            //print(JSON[eachOne]["media"]!)
            //print(JSON[eachOne]["media"]!!.count)

            let thisMediaView = JSON[eachOne]["media"]!.count

            for eachMedia in 0 ..< thisMediaView!{
                //print(JSON[eachOne]["media"]!![eachMedia]["media_url"])
                **let documentURL = JSON[eachOne]["media"]!![eachMedia]["media_url"]!**
                let pathus = URL(string: documentURL as! String)


                if pathus != nil {

                    HttpDownloader.loadFileSync(pathus!, completion:{(path:String, error:NSError!) in
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use AnyObject anymore, use "Any?"

Comment: define each of them :Array, String, Dictionary separately in (let documentURL = JSON[eachOne]["media"]....)

Comment: I've tried with "Any", but it produces the same error

Comment: @MAhipalSingh can you show me an example please?

Comment: let JSON = JSON as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                            let dic1 = JSON["eachOne"] as!  Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                            let arrMedia = object["media"] as!  Array Some thing like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a beginning Swift programmer you should pretend that the `!` force unwrap operator doesn't exist. I call it the "crash if nil" operator. Instead, you should use `if let` or `guard let` optional binding. You cast your JSON object as a an array of dictionaries, so use the array directly:

```
for anObject in JSON {
   guard let mediaArray = anObject["media"] as [[String: Any]] else 
   { 
     return
   }
   for aMediaObject in mediaArray {
     guard let aMediaDict = aMediaObject as? [String: Any],
       let documentURLString = aMediaDict["media_url"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string: documentURLString ) else 
     {
        return
     }
     //The code below is extracted from your question. It has multiple
     //issues, like using force-unwrap, and the fact that it appears to be
     //a synchronous network call?
     HttpDownloader.loadFileSync(pathus!, 
       completion:{(path:String, error:NSError!) in {
     }
   }
}
```

That code might not be perfect, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Hi Duncan C, Thank you.
I'm trying to implement your code, please take a look at this!
[link](http://hibiscus.li/ios/er.png)

Comment: Ok, so think it through. The compiler doesn't know that the object from the array is a dictionary, so you have to add clause to the guard statement to cast it to the correct type. I'll edit my answer to add the appropriate code. (Don't post pictures of code. It's very hard to use.)

Comment: Thank you Duncan C, It seems to work now :) Thanx a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, but don't just copy/paste the code I gave you in without understanding it. Go read up on optionals, unwrapping, guard statements, `if let` optional binding, etc. These are CENTRAL topics to learning Swift, and the sooner you get comfortable with them, the better off you'll be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following line in your code produces an Int, not an Array:

```
let thisMediaView = JSON[eachOne]["media"]!.count
```

Second, you could force-unwrap all your values, but that bring a lot of risk. You should not force-unwrap unless... no wait, just don't force-unwrap.

Your line here makes a lot of assumptions on the type of values that are in your JSON, without actually checking.

```
let documentURL = JSON[eachOne]["media"]!![eachMedia]["media_url"]!
```

To be a lot safer and more expressive, try to write it as follows:

```
if let value = JSON[eachOne] as? [String: Any],
   let anotherValue = JSON[value] as? [String: Any],
   ...etc,
   let documentURL = anotherValue["media_url"] as? String {
   // do something with the values
} else {
   // handle unexpected value or ignore
}
```